# Retrieving an array via JNA

Tags: java, x11, jna

I've got an problem with getting information back from a memory block allocated by the called function. Specifically, there's function `XGetWindowProperties` in the X11 lib included with JNA. It returns the results via the last parameter - `PointerByReference prop_return`.

I know the actual memory area contains an array of `Window`. But how do I create those objects? I don't see any way to get it from the pointer itself and I can't get a `Buffer` from it, since I don't know the size of `Window`.

The real function is: `int XGetWindowProperty(...., unsigned char **prop_return)` and with the parameters I'm calling it with, it's actually `int XGetWindowProperty(...., Window *prop_return[])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the elements in the returned data is defined by the returned "format" from XGetWindowProperty(), with one annoying exception. Xlib always returns format 32 as an array of "long" even if "long" is 64-bit. Window would have format 32.

In a quick google search, you can use NativeLong.SIZE to determine this in JNA.
So if (NativeLong.SIZE == 8) you have a buffer of 64-bit window IDs, otherwise of 32-bit window IDs.

The byte order of each value should match the CPU you're on.

Comment: While this solves my immediate problem, I'd still like to see a general solution: how to go from PointerByReference to an array of known native-mapped types.

Comment: yeah, I can't answer the JNA question, only the Xlib question. fwiw "Window" is just an integer ID, it isn't an object in any meaningful sense.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to extract the data first as an array of primitive type (int or long as appropriate).  you can then construct X11.Window objects as needed using the XIDs from the array.

It *is* possible to set up converters to handle some of this automatically, but ultimately it's simpler for a one-off to do the conversion explicitly.